# Run Python localhost through Grunt

Tags: python, gruntjs

I am relatively new to Gruntjs, but I've managed to get everything running automatically, except my localhost.

How can I make Grunt run `python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000 --insecure` ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use grunt-shell https://github.com/sindresorhus/grunt-shell

Try something like this:

```
grunt.initConfig({
    shell: {
        pythonServer: {
            options: {
                stdout: true
            },
            command: 'python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000 --insecure'
        }
    }
});

grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-shell');
grunt.registerTask('default', ['shell:pythonServer']);
```

I hope it helps :)
Cheers

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction(would've never guessed to look for 'shell'). I ended up using https://npmjs.org/package/grunt-bg-shell because sass and the server were overwriting each other.

Comment: More reasons to love Grunt.

Comment: Thank you Tobias from the past. You helped me to solve my problem in the future .... i mean now :D